# Exception While Using Rest API developed using JAX-RS Plugin with Spring Security Core Plugin

Tags: java, spring-security, jersey, jax-rs, grails-plugin

I am working on Grails Application. I created RestApi using Jaxr Plugin. And later on I added Spring Security Core Plugin to authorize and authenticate my resources. But after adding this plugIn, my Rest API Stopped working and I got this exception:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.decide(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.java:47)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
at org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter.doFilterInternal(JaxrsFilter.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think, this was due to Spring Security Core PlugIn which was not allowing this URL. So I added this URL in Static Mapping too as Follow:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
......

'/MediaSenseEvents/SessionEvents': ['permitAll'],

.....
]
```

But after that too it should allow this URL, But I am still getting this issue. Can anyone guide me regarding this ? Do I need to do something else ? or anything wrong ?

Your guidance will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Grails jax-rs plugin mappes by default "/api" path to JaxrsController (in JaxrsUrlMappings). So try to enable the "/api/**" path in your static rules.

Comment: I have changed that default path in the configuration file of plugin. And It was running out of the box before using spring security core with the same URL.