# Issues while working with Spring Security Rest Plugin

Tags: spring, rest, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am working on Grails Application. I created RestApi using Jaxr Plugin. And later on I added Spring Security Core Plugin to authorize and authenticate my resources. When I added this Spring Security Core Plugin my REST API stopped working that I mentioned over there too:
 [Exception While Using Rest API developed using JAX-RS Plugin with Spring Security Core Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809310/exception-while-using-rest-api-developed-using-jaxr-plugin-with-spring-security)

So, I used Spring Security Rest Plugin to secire my Rest API. I followed the whole documentation. I succeed to generate authorization token.

Here is my Config.groovy file portion where I add chain map in order to validate:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/MediaSenseEvents/SessionEvents': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter',  // Stateless chain
    '/MediaSenseEvents/login': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter',  // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                          // Traditional chain
```

]

And, I have added the path for API Call too:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
....
'/MediaSenseEvents/SessionEvents': ['permitAll'],
....
]
```

Here '/MediaSenseEvents/SessionEvents' is the path of my API Calls.
And endpointUrl = '/MediaSenseEvents/login'

And this is my Event Listener Class which listens for API Calls make to it:

```
@Path('/MediaSenseEvents/SessionEvents')
class EventsListener {

@POST
//@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Consumes("application/json")
//@Secured(['permitAll'])
public String postRequest(String message, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException        {
...........
}
```

Now, I am unable to understand the how may I use this generated token to secure my REST API calls. I am still not getting able to make REST API calls and I using JAXR PlugIn to implement rest API.

Comment: I believe your static rules is not processed correctly. Have you tried with `@Secure` annotation instead? Also, I'd need to see a full debug output to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your Config.groovy? You've to add urls into chain map in order to validate something like:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
   '/v1/secure/api/**':'restTokenValidationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor',// Stateless chain
]
```

And then send the generated token in header, in order to change the header parameter name have a look at following property

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName = 'X-Auth-Token'
```

Comment: I have added my Config.groovy file with the chain map parameter. Is everything fine over there ?

Comment: Update: Before Specifying validation header name while making API Calls I was getting error: 401-Unauthorized
But, Now when I specified validation Header name with generated token I get error: 403-Forbidden